# Game only checks for winner sometimes

Tags: python

The code runs perfect only sometimes. The check to see if the players total is = 20 seems to not run sometimes. I can run this and get a winner and then run again and it just keeps adding beyond 20. What causes this? And is there a better way to think about building a function?

Here is my code:

```
from random import randint

#Setting starting space to 0, getting user names and printing
#welcome message.
current_space1 = 0
current_space2 = 0   
player_1 = raw_input('Enter player 1 name: ')
player_2 = raw_input('Enter player 2 name: ')
print('\nWelcome ' + player_1 + ' and ' + player_2)
print('\nLet\'s Play!\n')


#making a function to roll dice, update current_space, check
#to see if current_space == end of game and if not move onto
#player_2 roll
def roll_1():
    global current_space1
    print(current_space1)
    if current_space1 == 20:
        print('You are the winner ' + player_1 + '!')
    elif current_space1 != 20:
        roll_dice = raw_input(player_1 + ' roll dice? y or n: ')
        if roll_dice == 'y': 
            rolled_dice = (randint(1,6))
            print(player_1 + ' ' + 'rolled ' + str(rolled_dice))
            current_space1 += rolled_dice
            print(current_space1)
            if current_space1 == 20:
                print('You are the winner ' + player_1 + '!')
            elif current_space1 != 20:
                roll_2()                


def roll_2():
    global current_space2
    print(current_space2)
    if current_space2 == 20:
        print('You are the winner ' + player_2 + '!')
    elif current_space2 != 20:
        roll_dice = raw_input(player_2 + ' roll dice? y or n: ')
        if roll_dice == 'y': 
            rolled_dice = (randint(1,6))
            print(player_2 + ' ' + 'rolled ' + str(rolled_dice))
            current_space2 += rolled_dice
            print(current_space2)
            if current_space2 == 20:
                print('You are the winner ' + player_2 + '!')
            elif current_space2 != 20:
                roll_1()


roll_1()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking if `current_space` is equal to 20, where as there could be cases where it could be greater than 20 (Say, when the user is at 19 and the next roll is 6)

Replace `if current_space1 == 20`, with `if current_space1 >= 20`

Do the same for `current_space2`